# How do I write to a specific position in a wstring array?

Tags: c++, wstring

I have a wstring named map and want to write to a specific position in that wstring array. I am able to read characters from specific positions, but I do not know how to write to this wstring other than to append to it.

```
float fPlayerX;
float fPlayerY;
int nMapWidth = 16;
int nMapHeight = 16;
bool GotO;

wstring map

map += L"################";
map += L"#G.............X";
map += L"#..............#";
map += L"#..............#";
map += L"#..............#";
map += L"#..............#";
map += L"#..............#";
map += L"#..............#";
map += L"#..............#";
map += L"#..............#";
map += L"#..............#";
map += L"#..............#";
map += L"#......O.......#";
map += L"#..............#";
map += L"#..............#";
map += L"################";

if (map.c_str()[(int)fPlayerX * nMapWidth + (int)fPlayerY] == 'O')
{
    // Pick up O
    if (GotO == false)
    { 
        // WRITE A "." TO WHERE THE O IS RIGHT NOW
    }
}
```

If I try

```
map[(int)fPlayerX * nMapWidth + (int)fPlayerY] = L".";
```

or

```
map[(int)fPlayerX * nMapWidth + (int)fPlayerY] = ".";
```

I get

```
Error   C2440   '=': cannot convert from 'const wchar_t [2]' to 'wchar_t'
```

Comment: Why not start out with something simple, like a 3 x 3 or even a 2 x 2 layout to get an understanding of how to write to a certain location?  Also, it isn't a good idea to name your variable `map`.

Comment: What about `map[index] = '.'`, where `index` is the position that you have computed?

Comment: @MartinUeding If I try `map[(int)fPlayerX * nMapWidth + (int)fPlayerY] = ".";`
I get the following: `Error C2440 '=': cannot convert from 'const char [2]' to 'wchar_t'`
This is what I first tried.

Comment: Use `'` instead of `"`!. The expression `'.'` is of type `char`, whereas `"."` actually means the array `{'.', '\0'}` and is of type `char const *`.

Comment: This is why you start out simple first -- this is how you learn different concepts.  You should have seen that `std::wstring x = L"abc"; x[0] = "1";` wouldn't work.  If a simple case like that fails, why complicate matters by introducing a bunch of strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map[index] = '.'`, where index is the position that you have computed.

Be careful to use `'` instead of `"`!. The expression `'.'` is of type char, whereas `"."` actually means the array `{'.', '\0'}` and is of type `char const *`.

Comment: Thank you. I am new to wstrings and didn't know the syntax.

Comment: See for instance [cpp reference](https://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).